# How to run code when a WebView has finished loading.

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiwebview

I have 2 WebViews in my application. one is loading a youtube video and the other is loading an events calendar. I want to show a custom 'Loading' image until the data from the web views are done loading.

I am trying

```
while([youtubeView isLoading]){
        NSLog(@"youtubeVideo is loading");
        [loadingImage setHidden:NO];
    }
    [loadingImage setHidden:YES];
```

In viewDidLoad but it doesn't work.

Whats the best way to accomplish what I am trying to achieve?

Cheers, Beers on me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below method of UIWebViewDelegate. It get called once webView finish loading.

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
    {
        if(youtubeView isEqual:webView)
        {
           loadingImage.hidden = YES;
        }
    }
```

Also note that your class need to conform to UIWebViewDelegate and both your webviews should set delegate equal to object of that class.

```
@interface YourViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>
{
    UIWebView *youtubeView;
}
@end
```

inside method where you create UIWebView youtubeView

```
youtubeView.delegate = self;
```

Beer ?

Comment: you sir... are a god. Ill err send the beer in the post.

Comment: gotta wait four minutes to accept your answer now. Life is hard.

Comment: would it be ok to say if([youtubeView isEqual:webView] && [anotheryoutubeView isEqual:webView]) ? would that work?

Comment: if([youtubeView isEqual:webView] || [anotheryoutubeView isEqual:webView])   Use || (or, either is true not && (and) which is never possible. How can webview be equal to both :)